# Insert formula into cell with VBA: Object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use this in my VBA code:

```
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1:).Formula = "='Sheet1'!A1" & Chr(34) & Chr(47) & Chr(34) & "'Sheet1'!A2"
```

This gives me Error: 1004, Object-defined error.

I'd like to see in the cell formula that:

> ='Sheet1'!A1"/"'Sheet1'!A2

And if the value of the A1 cell is 10 and the A2 value is 20, the cell value should look like that:  **10/20**

What can be the problem?

Comment: Do you need to use a formula or can you just use VBA to do the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a colon instead of a speech mark within `Range`. You could try something like:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Sheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & "/" & Sheet("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

I'd also recommend not using `ActiveSheet` as much as possible and also referring to the workbook in references. If you want to refer to the workbook that contains the VBA code you can use `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: However, this answer hard-codes the values of A1 and A2 into the formula; if the new formula needs to use any updates to A1 and A2, then do not use `Sheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value` (this just pulls in A1's value into the formula, not a reference to A1 - check the resulting formula to see the result)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the formula to either read:

`='Sheet1'!A1&"/"&'Sheet1'!A2`  (so: textual concatenation of A1 & A2 with a "/" in between)

or

`='Sheet1'!A1/'Sheet1'!A2`  (so: the result of dividing A1 by A2)

Check the result of your formula: it generates neither :) (it results in an invalid formula)  And, as Jordan answered, your VBA used a colon instead of a double quote.

**UPDATE** (read over the fact that you asked for textual concatenation in your question, and also adding a solution)

It's best to check the result of your formula build-up while stepping through VBA with the debugger (F8): it generates an invalid formula, on which Excel will no doubt give you an error when you try to set it.  The result doesn't contain any `&` characters to concatenate the values of A1 & A2 with the "/" in between.

The correct formula should be:

```
='Sheet1'!A1&"/"&'Sheet1'!A2
```

This is achieved by:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Formula = "='Sheet1'!A1&""/""&'Sheet1'!A2"
```

(note that you can embed a " in a VBA string by doubling it; in this case that is clearer to read than using Chr(34) for the "'s)